# What is a secure way for user to update password, can't get form_for to call the right action in Rails 4?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, forms, authentication, ruby-on-rails-4

I have a form where I want to make it possible for users to change their password. I don't use Devise or anything like that. Before changing their passwords I want them to enter their current password, and I want to do it in an secure way. The form looks something like this:

```
--------------------
I Current password I
--------------------
--------------------
I Password         I
--------------------
--------------------
I Confirm password I
--------------------
  ---------------
  I   Submit    I
  ---------------
```

In my `UsersController` I have two methods that look like this:

```
def edit_password
end

def change_password
  # Probably not correct, but I want to make sure that the current password is correct before the user can change password.
  if @user.authenticate(params[:current_password])
    respond_to do |format|
      if @user.update_attributes(user_params)

        format.html { redirect_to(@user, :notice => 'Your account was successfully updated') }
        format.json { respond_with_bip(@user) }
      else
        format.html { render :action => "edit" }
        format.json { respond_with_bip(@user) }
      end
    end
  else
    redirect_to edit_user_path(@user), notice: "Your current password was incorrect"
  end
end
```

The form is displayed in my edit form action. My routes look like this:

```
resources :users do

  get 'edit_password', to: "users#edit_password"
  put 'change_password', to: "users#change_password"

end
```

My form looks like this:

```
= form_for @user, :url => user_change_password_path(@user) do |f|

  .form-group
    = f.label :current_password
    = f.text_field :current_password
  .form-group
    = f.label :password
    = f.password_field :password
  .form-group
    = f.label :password_confirmation
    = f.password_field :password_confirmation
  .form-actions
    = f.submit "Update Account"
```

In my user model I have `attr_accessor :current_password`.

When I click submit I currently get this error:

```
No route matches [PATCH] "/users/1/change_password"
```

So, how can I get it to work, is my current approach secure, and, if not, what should I change?

Comment: run `rake routes` and check results. Also, have you restarted the server after changing the routes?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To fix the routes issue, please, at your config/routes.rb change this:

```
put 'change_password', to: "users#change_password"
```

with this:

```
patch 'change_password', to: "users#change_password"
```

Because with explicit put the patch alias is not defined.

The way you are doing is pretty standard, authenticate with old password and then let change it.

Perhaps you want to remove the id from url and change only the current_user's password, but I don't think its an issue, because you are asking for the current password.

Comment: Thanks for your answer, that helped. But now I'm having some issues with the `.authenticate` method. I'm not sure how to get the parameters right. This is the params I get: `"user"=>{"current_password"=>"[FILTERED]", "password"=>"[FILTERED]", "password_confirmation"=>"[FILTERED]"}`, I try to use it like this: `if @user.authenticate(params[:current_password].merge(email: @user.email))`. This results in the error: `NoMethodError (undefined method merge' for nil:NilClass)`, any ideas what I can do to fix it?

Comment: You don't need to merge with email to call authenticate, `@user.authenticate(params[:current_password])` is correct. But, `params[:current_password]` must not be nil. To see filtered params you can modify `config/application.rb`, searching and setting `config.filter_params = []`